# CodeIgniter DataTable with hyperlink

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, electron

How can I pass data from datatable using hyperlink. I want to pass it by id. here is my code.

[my controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQx3e.png)

[my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMod7.png)

[index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUAAU.png)

I want to pass the data here when i click User ID. Thank you.

[Student Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IGml.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can create the hyperlink on foreach loop.
Eg. `<?php echo base_url('/users/' . $id ); ?>`

After you need to create the route record.
Eg. `$routes['/users/(:num)'] = 'login/view/$1';`

Lastly, create the method that will receive the ID clicked and do what you want.

```
public function view( $id ) {
     echo $id;
}
```